# InAppPurchasing using Cordova Phonegap Telerik/Icenium returning "invalid product id"

Tags: cordova, telerik, in-app-purchase, cordova-3, telerik-appbuilder

I'm struggling to find anyone who has an example project from which I can follow all the instructions. And Im seriously getting frustrated with the processes on Apple's side. I think I have everything set up correctly, but the app is not recognising the productid's that im supplying to it.

I am using [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) (previously icenium), using jQueryMobile 1.3.1, Cordova 3.2.0 and the [PhoneGap InAppPurchase iOS plugin](https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS)

I have created a public bitbucket repo so that you can see all the code [here](https://bitbucket.org/haxxxton/inapptutorial/src/).

**A. Apple side**

1. In iTunesConnect my app details are:
   [image]
   and is at the status **Waiting For Upload**
2. My InAppPurchases section looks like this:
   [image]
   i had heard that perhaps the reason the products werent being found was because they didnt have the sku prepending them. so i have some products with it and others without it just to be safe. [Issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194050/ios7-xcode5-how-to-resolve-invalid-product-id-for-in-app-purchases-in-2014).
3. I have created a sandbox itunes account in readiness for the ability to test purchases. (not that it is reaching a point i can test this yet)

---

**B. Telerik side**

1. I have basically followed the [3 Steps Tutorial for PhoneGap In-App Purchase on iOS](http://fovea.cc/blog/index.php/3-steps-tutorial-for-phonegap-in-app-purchase-on-ios/) with some minor changes so that the `initialize` function happens on `deviceready`. I have removed code not that is not reached as all the products return invalid, the code looks like this:

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello, World</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="jquery-mobile/styles/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-mobile/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery-mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--Home-->
        <div id="home" data-role="page">

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
                navigator.splashscreen.hide();
                IAP.initialize();
            }, false);
        </script>
        <script src="scripts/login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**login.js**

```
    var IAP = {
        list: [ 'dummyinapp11', 'dummyinapp12', 'com.gaandder.inapptutorial.dummyinapp11', 'com.gaandder.inapptutorial.dummyinapp12', 'com.gaandder.inapptutorial.dummyinapp1', 'com.gaandder.inapptutorial.dummyinapp2', 'dummyinapp1', 'dummyinapp2' ],
        products: {}
    };

    IAP.initialize = function () {
        // Check availability of the storekit plugin
        if (!window.storekit) {
            logg('In-App Purchases not available');
            return;
        }

        // Initialize
        storekit.init({
            ready:    IAP.onReady,
            purchase: IAP.onPurchase,
            restore:  IAP.onRestore,
            error:    IAP.onError
        });
    };

    IAP.onReady = function () {
        // Once setup is done, load all product data.
        storekit.load(IAP.list, function (products, invalidIds) {
            logg('IAPs loading done:');
            for (var j = 0; j < products.length; ++j) {
                var p = products[j];
                logg('Loaded IAP(' + j + '). title:' + p.title +
                            ' description:' + p.description +
                            ' price:' + p.price +
                            ' id:' + p.id);
                IAP.products[p.id] = p;
            }
            IAP.loaded = true;
            for (var i = 0; i < invalidIds.length; ++i) {
                logg('Error: could not load ' + invalidIds[i]);
            }
        });
    };

    logg = function (data) {
        document.getElementById('home').innerHTML += data + '<br />';
        // console.log(data);
    };
```

As you can see I have added all of the permutations of the product id's that i can think of, see A.2. for reasoning

---

**C. Device side**

1. I have logged out of iTunes on my ipad.
2. As you can see, each item is returned as invalid. [image]

---

**D. Other**

I have seen that perhaps I need to wait 24 hours after submitting the products for them to work: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371184/ios-in-app-purchase-invalid-product-id-in-release-not-development-version). However, this issue was with regards to a production ready app, not during testing. [This second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098207/phonegap-cordova-inapppurchasemanager-invalid-product-ids?rq=1) suggests that it again might just be a case of waiting longer.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you signed the developer contract with apple to allow IAPs?

Comment: yeah, i did that when i set up the App Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like this was just a case of waiting for the products to propagate onto all the Apple servers. Upon checking again today this is the result:

[image]